# PostGIS Window Functions (accoring to https://postgis.net/docs chapter 13.2) errors

Tags: postgis, function

i have just tried to run some of the examples on [posgits.net/docs 13.2 - windows functions](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/es/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html) and took the code from the examples provided by the corresponding pages. the following functions returned an error: [42883]: ERROR: function XY() does not exist.

- ST_CoverageInvalidEdges()
- ST_ClusterIntersectingWin()
- ST_ClusterWithinWin()
- ST_CoverageSimplify()

the following code, for instance, is from the exaple section of the [ST_CoverageInvalidEdges doc page](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/es/ST_CoverageInvalidEdges.html) and returns the before mentioned error:

```
WITH coverage(id, geom) AS (VALUES
  (1, 'POLYGON ((10 190, 30 160, 40 110, 100 70, 120 10, 10 10, 10 190))'::geometry),
  (2, 'POLYGON ((100 190, 10 190, 30 160, 40 110, 50 80, 74 110.5, 100 130, 140 120, 140 160, 100 190))'::geometry),
  (3, 'POLYGON ((140 190, 190 190, 190 80, 140 80, 140 190))'::geometry),
  (4, 'POLYGON ((180 40, 120 10, 100 70, 140 80, 190 80, 180 40))'::geometry)
)
SELECT id, ST_AsText(ST_CoverageInvalidEdges(geom) OVER ())
FROM coverage;
```

I could not find any documentation about that kind of errors. Are there any experiences related to that, any workarounds or hints about option to be set ...

Comment: Do you have versions that meet the documented requirements "Availability: 3.4.0 Requires GEOS >= 3.12.0"?

Comment: according to the docs postgis 3.4 should meet the requirements. and I do have 3.4 - but I didn't go into the details of any further requirements within the extension

Comment: There seems to be two requirements, PostGIS version and GEOS version. What is your GEOS version? You can see it with `select postgis_full_version()`.

Comment: @roberttuw You can refer to [this doc](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS#PostGISSupportMatrix): PostGIS 3.4 can ship with any GEOS version between 3.6 and 3.13, and [`ST_CoverageInvalidEdges()` doc](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/es/ST_CoverageInvalidEdges.html) mentions that it *Requires GEOS >= 3.12.0*. On PostgreSQL 16 PostGIS 3.4 with GEOS 3.11 ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jDduePYK)) the error is a bit more specific: *ERROR:  The GEOS version this PostGIS binary was compiled against (31101) doesn't support 'GEOSCoverageIsValid' function (3.12.0+ required)*